# Testcontainers RabbitMq with SSL/TLS fails to wait for a container to start

Tags: ssl, rabbitmq, testcontainers

I have a test using RabbitMq in Testcontainers. The test is working using HTTP

```
@Container private static final RabbitMQContainer RABBITMQ_CONTAINER =
          new RabbitMQContainer()
                  .withLogConsumer(new Slf4jLogConsumer(LOG))
                  .withStartupTimeout(Duration.of(5, ChronoUnit.MINUTES))
                  .waitingFor(Wait.forHttp("/api/vhosts")
                          .forPort(15672)
                          .withBasicCredentials("guest", "guest"));
```

and fails when I switch to HTTPS

```
@Container private static final RabbitMQContainer RABBITMQ_CONTAINER =
          new RabbitMQContainer()
                  .withLogConsumer(new Slf4jLogConsumer(LOG))
                  .withStartupTimeout(Duration.of(5, ChronoUnit.MINUTES))
                  .waitingFor(Wait.forHttp("/api/vhosts")
                          .usingTls()
                          .forPort(15671)
                          .withBasicCredentials("guest", "guest"))
                  .withSSL(forClasspathResource("/certs/server_key.pem", 0644),
                          forClasspathResource("/certs/server_certificate.pem", 0644),
                          forClasspathResource("/certs/ca_certificate.pem", 0644),
                          VERIFY_NONE,
                          false);
```

In logs I see that container can not start:

```
...
18:53:21.274 [main] INFO  - /brave_swirles: Waiting for 60 seconds for URL: https://localhost:50062/api/vhosts (where port 50062 maps to container port 15671)
...
18:54:21.302 [main] ERROR - Could not start container
org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerLaunchException: Timed out waiting for URL to be accessible (https://localhost:50062/api/vhosts should return HTTP 200)
```

What do I miss? I'd want at least Testcontainers' waiting strategy works.

Answer (score 0):

Using `RabbitMQContainer` with custom SSL certificates makes it hard to also use `HttpWaitStrategy`. In this case, you probably need to configure the whole JVM to trust those SSL certificates.

Alternatively, just continue to use the default wait strategy (which will be a `LogMessageWaitStrategy`).

For further examples, just look at the `RabbitMQContainer` tests in Testcontainers itself:
https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/blob/c3f53b3a63e6b0bc800a7f0fbce91ce95a8986b3/modules/rabbitmq/src/test/java/org/testcontainers/containers/RabbitMQContainerTest.java#L237-L264

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do parameters SslVerification=VERIFY_NONE and failIfNoCert=false mean that every https call to 15671 with or without correct certificate should pass? 
In my case as 3.7.25-management-alpine container is used I want to connect to https management port 15671. But in any case calling with correct certificates or without any I have an exception when rabbitmq doesn't respond to clients handshake. Looks like server doesn't listen on 15671.
`TransportContext.java:363|Fatal (HANDSHAKE_FAILURE): Couldn't kickstart handshaking`

Comment: I don't know where you set those parameters, so I can't give you any information on this.